# How can I count the qtyInstock of each instance of a size and color

Tags: oracle

Here is the table -

```
create table inventoryItem (
       itemNum    varchar(10) not null
              references itemType(itemNum) on delete cascade,
       code   varchar(20) not null,
       qtyInstock float       not null,
       itemColor  varchar(15),
       itemSize   float,
       primary key (itemNum, code)
```

This is the values -

```
insert into inventoryItem values ('A0', 'pbk', 30, 'black', 3.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('B1', 'hbk', 50, 'white', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A0', 'hbk', 25, 'green', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('C2', 'hbk', 20, 'black', 3.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('C1', 'ebk', 70, 'black', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A3', 'pbk', 30, 'black', 2.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A2', 'pbk', 50, 'green', 3.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('A0', 'ebk', 15, 'green', 4.0);
insert into inventoryItem values ('C2', 'pbk', 30, 'black', 3.0);
```

This is what I have tried -

```
select itemSize, itemColor, SUM(qtyInstock ) as stock_combination
from inventoryItem
group by itemSize, itemColor;
```

Further explanation - I want to create a view showing the `itemNum` `itemSize` `itemColor` and a count of how much `qtyInstock` there is for each instance of a color and size. For example - how much stock is there for a black shirt in size 3 or a white shirt in size 2. I've been lost for hours and have no idea how to go about this. Please help! Thank you to anyone who comments :)

Comment: Should itenNum represent color&size? It doesn't make sense for the same itemNum to represent different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch all perm/combination of color and size against itemnum.
Will return 0 as stock qty if that combination does not exist in the inventory -

Actual table -

```
select * from inventoryitem;

ITEMNUM    CODE  QTYINSTOCK ITEMCOLOR         ITEMSIZE
---------- ----- ---------- --------------- ----------
A0         pbk           30 black                    3
B1         hbk           50 white                    4
A0         hbk           25 green                    4
C2         hbk           20 black                    3
C1         ebk           70 black                    4
A3         pbk           30 black                    2
A2         pbk           50 green                    3
A0         ebk           15 green                    4
C2         pbk           30 black                    3

9 rows selected.
```

## Main Query

```
select
inum,icol,isize, sum(qnty) as total_qty from
(
with cte as
(
select a.itemnum as inum,b.itemcolor as icol,c.itemsize as isize, 0 as qnty from
(select distinct itemnum from inventoryitem) a,
(select distinct itemcolor from inventoryitem) b,
(select distinct itemsize from inventoryitem) c
)
select cte.inum,cte.icol,cte.isize,cte.qnty from cte
union
select itemnum,itemcolor, itemsize, qtyInstock from inventoryItem
)
group by inum,icol,isize
order by inum,icol;

INUM       ICOL                 ISIZE  TOTAL_QTY
---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
A0         black                    2          0
A0         black                    3         30
A0         black                    4          0
A0         green                    2          0
A0         green                    3          0
A0         green                    4         40
A0         white                    2          0
A0         white                    3          0
A0         white                    4          0
A2         black                    2          0
A2         black                    3          0
A2         black                    4          0
A2         green                    2          0
A2         green                    3         50
A2         green                    4          0
A2         white                    2          0
A2         white                    3          0
A2         white                    4          0
A3         black                    2         30
A3         black                    3          0
A3         black                    4          0
A3         green                    2          0
A3         green                    3          0
A3         green                    4          0
A3         white                    2          0
A3         white                    3          0
A3         white                    4          0
B1         black                    2          0
B1         black                    3          0
B1         black                    4          0
B1         green                    2          0
B1         green                    3          0
B1         green                    4          0
B1         white                    2          0
B1         white                    3          0
B1         white                    4         50
C1         black                    2          0
C1         black                    3          0
C1         black                    4         70
C1         green                    2          0
C1         green                    3          0
C1         green                    4          0
C1         white                    2          0
C1         white                    3          0
C1         white                    4          0
C2         black                    2          0
C2         black                    3         50
C2         black                    4          0
C2         green                    2          0
C2         green                    3          0
C2         green                    4          0
C2         white                    2          0
C2         white                    3          0
C2         white                    4          0

54 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query gives what you indicate you are looking for, except you cannot add itemNum and get the correct total as you would need to add it to the `group by`. (I guess that is what you are discovering.) The solution is the *Analytic function* version of `sum`.  (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9f88cee9341cdba6aaa16d23a5a820e5))

```
select itemNum
     , itemSize
     , itemColor
     , qtyInstock
     , sum(qtyInstock ) over (partition by itemSize,  itemColor)  as stock_combination
  from inventoryItem
 order by itemSize,  itemColor, itemNum;
```

I added the `qtyinstock` for each as without it the results seem distorted, and perhaps still as it does not include `code`. But that is easily removed.